# Python read file line by line and multiply

Tags: python

I have a text file that is similar to this:

```
line 1: a b c,
line 2: d e f,
line 3: g h i
```

I need to write a python code that reads the file and print the first value of each line and multiply the last two to something like this:

```
line 1: a, bc 
line 2: d, ef
line 3: g, hi
```

Please help anyone

EDIT: a, d and g are non numeric values, b, c, e, f, h and i are numeric values

Comment: Are a, b and c numbers? It's not clear from your question how they're supposed to be multiplied.

Comment: a, d and g are non numeric values, b, c, e, f, h and i are numeric values

Comment: How far have you gotten?  Show your code.

Comment: You can `split` on spaces for each line in your file and cast the second and third values to `int` (or `float`) and multiply. From there you can simply print out values as needed

Comment: Ain't got much yet. Found help somewhere else to get this:
  with open('file.txt') as file:
    while (line := file.readline().rstrip()):
        print(line)
  I guess I have to remove that print command and replace it, but I do not know with what. Please note im brand new to python.

Comment: @erdnisra please go and try my solution below and tell me if it works.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is the code that you need:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
   numbers = []
   for line in file.readlines()[1:]:
      for number in line.replace(',', '').split(' '):
         numbers.append(number)
      print(f'{number[0]}, {float(number[1])*float(number[2])}')
```

Comment: Getting error: NameError: name 'lines' is not defined

Comment: Sorry didnt see the edit. New error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'b'

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'b'

Comment: Could it be due to this: Also forgot that the first line goes like this: 'Isotope weight [g/mol] Natural abundance'.

Comment: Got the multiplication right. Thanks!

Comment: Just accept my answer so I get better reputation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
with open(filename) as file:              # Opens the file
    for line in file:                     # Loops through each line in file.
        line = line.rstrip()              # Removes any spaces in the right.
    a, b, c = line.split(" ")             # Split based on spaces
    print(a + " " + str(int(b) * int(c)))
```

In the last line b and c are converted to `integer`, multiplied and then changed to `str` again so that our final string can be prepared for `print()`.

Comment: Im getting an error: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

Comment: Are you sure your input file has like a b c ? Are there any leading spaces ?

Comment: This error means that each line cannot be split into 3 parts with `space` as a separator.

Comment: Not sure what a leading space is. Also forgot that the first line goes like this: 'Isotope weight [g/mol] Natural abundance'. Then rest mentioned above